# String.replaceAll(string,string) method gives unexpexted output

Tags: java, android, string, string-conversion

I have some amounts as input like:

**Rs1 ,
 INR10,954.00 ,
 INR 45000 ,
 INR 25000.70 ,
 Rs.25000 ,
 Rs.1,000 ,
 Rs. 14000**
 these are the input formats I'm using

```
    String getRuppee="Rs1"; // this string can not get the format and gives wrong output.

    String val=getRuppee.toLowerCase()
                    .replaceAll(",", "")
                    .replaceAll("rs.", "")
                    .replaceAll("\"rs\"", "")
                    .replaceAll("rs", "")
                    .replaceAll("inr", "")
                    .replaceAll("inr ", "")
                    .replaceAll("mrp", "")
                    .replaceAll(" ", "");
```

This is how i get the output as per input show above, unless the first (Rs1).

```
Log.e("Converstion", "Converstion Balance."
                +getRuppee.toLowerCase().

                replaceAll("rs.", ""));
```

i need the output 1 but it gives me null.

Logcat Displays: **"06-07 11:34:48.438: E/Converstion(8233): Converstion Balance."**

Comment: You need to escape the `.` using `\\.`. Also, honestly, your question is unclear. Show us exact input and output

Comment: its not working , i try this , it gives me  06-07 12:00:51.408: E/Converstion(12706): Converstion Balance.rs1

Comment: Again, show us the exact input format and expected output. Your question is unclear. Remove the unnecessary code (if any)

Comment: @SagarThakarar "rs." not found on getRupee

Comment: The format i shown up is the input , the the output is Null. the fist format i shown is Rs1 , and i want output only 1. but is giving null

Comment: can you explain clearly? what is your input and expected output?

Comment: @SagarThakarar Log.e("Converstion", "Converstion Balance."               +getRuppee.toLowerCase().replaceAll("rs", ""));

Comment: Thanks @TheLostMind , it's working.

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem here

```
.replaceAll("rs.", "")
```

As replaceAll is doing replacement based upon regexp, then this is replacing anything starting with `rs` followed by any char

Try using `.replace` instead which replaces all strings

Comment: i don't have single string , but multiple.

Comment: @SagarThakarar - `replace()` replaces "all" strings. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence)

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as follows

```
String getRuppee="Rs1"; // this string can not get the format and gives wrong output.

String val=getRuppee.toLowerCase()
                .replace(",", "")
                .replace("rs.", "")
                .replace("\"rs\"", "")
                .replace("rs", "")
                .replace("inr", "")
                .replace("inr ", "")
                .replace("mrp", "")
                .replace(" ", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
String[] getRuppee = {"RS1", "INR10","954.00" , "INR 45000" , "INR 25000.70" , "Rs.25000" , "Rs.1,000" , "Rs. 14000"};

         for (String tmp : getRuppee){
            String val=tmp.toLowerCase()
                            .replaceAll(",", "")
                            .replaceAll("rs\\.", "")  //check here
                            .replaceAll("\"rs\"", "")
                            .replaceAll("rs", "")
                            .replaceAll("inr", "")
                            .replaceAll("inr ", "")
                            .replaceAll("mrp", "")
                            .replaceAll(" ", "");
            System.out.println(val);
         }
```